# What modifications are needed to a 9V guitar pedal circuit to run it at 18V (not using batteries?)

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led, circuit-design

I design and build Vero circuit boards and am trying my hand at upping them to 18V for the extra headroom. No need for advise getting to 18V, I have 18V adapters and know my way around a voltage doubler.

I work with mostly 25V electrolytics (I have some 50V) and 1/4W resistors. I checked out several Vero designs of 18V pedals that all say 9V on the voltage input without any obvious modifications to the components except suggestions to "watch the electrolytic capacitors." I know the rule of thumb for the electrolytics is 2x the voltage.

Will 25V capacitors work? Do I need to check the non-polarized capacitors? They will probably be fine, I use mostly 50-100V monolithic ceramic 100V and polyester mylar when necessary. Any need to bump any resistors up to 1/2W? Also I don't like my LEDs to be blinding so depending on the color I usually use a 8.2-15k 1/4w resistor. Do I need to modify anything in the LED+ path for 18V usage?

Comment: It's impossible to say for certain without a schematic and bill of materials.

Comment: "*... for the extra headroom.*" Headroom would only be required if you're getting unintended or unwanted distortion. Are you?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the right Resistor Value and Wattage for use with 5 mm LED’s in 9V and 18V circuits
You will need to know the forward current and the forward voltage (Vf) of the LED.

My 5mm LED’s have a forward current of approximately 20mA (.02A). Their forward voltage ranges from 3.09Vf in the Clear Purple to 1.88Vf in the Clear Red. (example uses .02A, 3.09Vf at 9V)

Input Voltage = LED Vf + Resistor Voltage    (9V = 3.09Vf + Res V)

Res V (Voltage [dropped] Across Resistor ) = Input V - LED Vf    (Res V = 9V - 3.09Vf = 5.91V)

Using Ohm’s Law:
Resistance (in Ohms) = V/Current (in Amps)

Res V 5.91V/.02A = 295.5 ohm (rounding up is best so 300 ohm resistor)

And to check the resistors Wattage handling:

Total Wattage = Input V x forward current (9V x .02A = 1.8W)

LED Wattage = Vf x forward current    (3.09V x .02A = .0616 watts)

Wattage dissipated by resistor = Total Wattage - LED Wattage   (.18W - .0616W = .1184W)

Resistors (1/8W = .1875W, 1/4W = .25W, 1/2W = .5W)

Recommendations:
9V circuit and LED 3.09Vf is a 300 ohm 1/8W (or more).

9V circuit and LED 1.88Vf  360 ohm 1/4W.

18V circuit and LED 3.09Vf   750 ohm 1/2W.

18V circuit and LED 1.88Vf    820 ohm 1/2W.

Resistance Calculator
https://www.ledsupply.com/led-resistance-calculator

Comment: What does this have to do with the main question?

Comment: @ocrdu one of the questions asked was "Do I need to modify anything in the LED+ path for 18V usage?". Wattage also applies to resistors used in other parts of the circuit (as for what effect doubling the voltage will have on active components...).